# Why getting error ArgumentException: Texture2D.SetPixels: texture uses an unsupported format. (Texture )?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At top

```
public Texture2D source;
public Texture2D destination;
private int sourceMipLevel = 0;
```

the method start

```
void Start()
    {
        Test();
    }
```

Test method

```
private void Test()
    {
        // Get a copy of the color data from the source Texture2D, in high-precision float format.
        // Each element in the array represents the color data for an individual pixel.
        Color[] pixels = source.GetPixels(sourceMipLevel);

        // If required, manipulate the pixels before applying them to the destination Texture2D.
        // This example code reverses the array, which rotates the image 180 degrees.
        System.Array.Reverse(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

        // Set the pixels of the destination Texture2D.
        int destinationMipLevel = 0;
        destination.SetPixels(pixels, destinationMipLevel);

        // Apply changes to the destination Texture2D, which uploads its data to the GPU.
        destination.Apply();
    }
```

i tried to use image that is sprite 2d texture both source and destination same type of sprtie 2d texture but on the destination i'm getting the error in the editor :

I even tried to use the same image sprite 2d texture on both source and destination but still getting the same error.

The error is at line 68 :

```
destination.SetPixels(pixels, destinationMipLevel);
```

The error :

ArgumentException: Texture2D.SetPixels: texture uses an unsupported format. (Texture 'WithClouds')
UnityEngine.Texture2D.SetPixels (System.Int32 x, System.Int32 y, System.Int32 blockWidth, System.Int32 blockHeight, UnityEngine.Color[] colors, System.Int32 miplevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the documentation. Most errors are explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html).

Your issue is probably with the file being crunch compressed, as explained in [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/texture2d-getpixels-texture-uses-an-unsupported-format.1289612/).

“For this function to succeed, Texture.isReadable must be true and the data must not be Crunch compressed.”

Comment: Please include a minimal actual answer here as well, you can e.g. block quote the relevant parts of the linked pages ... don't only post links as they might "die" one day making your answer useless to anyone else